# Android gradle sync failed when integrated with firebase

Tags: android-studio, gradle, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I created new project in the fire base and and my android studio too , in the fire base I did all integrations as in the documentation including adding class path **com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0** into my gradle, after I finished I tried to sync my project it brings the error *no cached version of com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0 available for offline mode* ,(my work environment doesn't have access to internet) , is there a way to fix this without having 24/7 internet access ?(for offline case )

Comment: Please share your app and module gradle files

Comment: Please update this in the question not here

Comment: The answer is a bit OS specific could you please share which OS are you using ?

Comment: I'm using windows 8.1 64 bit

Comment: @gaurav4sarma I have default gradle config it worked perfectly before adding fire base to it , the problem came after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, But After you add  `com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0` to your gradle, it means that gradle have to download that package from that address or using jit-binary, etc.

So, you have to provide net access so that it can download that package while syncing.

Comment: But if i may ask  is there any way to download the jit binary package in another and install it manually ?I really need it if it's possible

Comment: no man! jit binary is a place where developers register n keep there packages, you can give it a try but believe me that would be painful..